# How to install and use Python 3.9+ in Vertex AI using Docker?

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, vertex, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

So I am working in an external organization's GCP project, and the policy is that there is no public internet access available. I want to use some Python modules that are not contained in the DL containers that are available for Vertex, so the only option is to build and push a docker container that installs those modules for me, then use it to create a jupyter notebook.

Here's the catch: I am trying to install a certain module version that requires at least Python 3.9, and that's where I am stuck now. I've accomplished building with Python 3.9 using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70866415/how-to-install-python-specific-version-on-docker) as a reference in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cpu:latest
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt install -y python3.9
RUN pip install gower
RUN pip install kmodes
RUN pip install ray
RUN pip install prince==0.9.0
```

But I am getting this error during build:

```
> [6/6] RUN pip install prince==0.9.0:
#0 1.325 ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.8.0 Requires-Python >=3.9,<4.0; 0.8.1 Requires-Python >=3.9,<4.0; 0.8.2 Requires-Python >=3.9,<4.0; 0.8.3 Requires-Python >=3.9,<4.0; 0.9.0 Requires-Python >=3.9,<4.0
#0 1.325 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement prince==0.9.0 (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 0.4.6, 0.4.7, 0.4.8, 0.4.9, 0.4.10, 0.5.2, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.7.0, 0.7.1)
#0 1.326 ERROR: No matching distribution found for prince==0.9.0
```

So I am assuming it is not finding the Python version previously installed and thus fails to build. I guess I am missing a couple of lines and/or instructions that would allow me to properly build and push this to Container Registry.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your image probably already has some python installed. Either remove it (e.g. `apt-get remove python3.8`) or call `python3.9 -m pip install ...` to reference exact python.

Comment: @SUTerliakov yes, the base 'gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cpu' has 3.7.X installed, including some other data science packages. Let's say I remove python 3.7 first, what happens to those packages when I install 3.9? Would I need to reinstall all of them? If so, then including a requirements.txt would be the best practice, I assume.

Comment: Yes, `requirements.txt` file instead of direct enumeration in Dockerfile can be helpful. You cannot (or should not, at least) reuse packages from python 3.7 in 3.9 - at least because they may be version-incompatible and require an upgrade to use 3.9. Ideally you should know which exactly packages you need and install them in Dockerfile (probably from requirements file).

Comment: Even if we use a `requirements.txt` for our desired packages, this would still be a problem for launching directly the jupyter notebook from Vertex AI Workbench. I think there are still some instructions missing on that Dockerfile to be able to run it properly with Vertex (an ENTRYPOINT, maybe?).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75982907/how-to-install-a-custom-container-with-latest-python-jupyterlab-version

Comment: @gogasca Thanks! Will keep this as a future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We release version m105 which includes Python 3.10. https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-containers/docs/release-notes

Comment: Thanks for the update @gogasca! Just for future reference, is there an optimal way to update the Python version on our own using the base DL containers? Or we'll have to wait for official releases?

Comment: Yes, there is an official way, instead of using our base Deep Learning containers, you would need to use a different base. Example: Python 3.11 (python:3.11.1), install JupyterLab and configure JupyterLab parameters to be able to connect through our Proxy. I opened a documentation bug to track this and have an official document, in the meantime will post an answer here for reference.

Comment: @gogasca any news on official documentation? I would like to create a custom container for python 3.11 duo to some features there. However, I would like to have an official process so gcp will not introduce breaking changes while developing the product further.

Comment: No official doc yet, this doc still holds true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75982907/how-to-install-a-custom-container-with-latest-python-jupyterlab-version